# Replace value with nan based on required quarters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As a part of model requirement, I am stuck on weird spot where I need to replace actual value with Nan for extra quarters.

In the below example, 
Id 1 should have nan in column Q4, 2 should have no nan and 3 should have Q3 and Q4 both as nan.

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2,3], 'QTR_req': [3,4,2],'Q1':[1,1,1],'Q2':[2,2,2],'Q3':[3,3,3],'Q4':[4,4,4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have reached till the part of accessing QTR_req using df.loc but then stuck on how to make specific quarter nan. Could you suggest what am I looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this:

```
df2[cols_needed] = (df2[ cols_needed ]
                       .where(df2['QTR_req'].values[:,None] >np.arange(len(cols_needed )) )
                             )
```

Output:

```
   ID  QTR_req  Q1  Q2   Q3   Q4
0   1        3   1   2  3.0  NaN
1   2        4   1   2  3.0  4.0
2   3        2   1   2  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It could work but hard coding columns(i.e. Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) is not a way. There might be n number of quarters. thanks for the help though.

Comment: Are the quarters always at the end of the dataframe? we can certainly do `iloc`. Else you need to pass `quarter_list` in stead of hard-coding. Also `4` should be replace by `num_quarters`.

Comment: quarter_list is something I can get with  ```cols_needed = list(df2.filter(regex='^Q',axis=1).columns)``` part and then value 4 with ```len(quarter_list)```. but it is not necessary that all the columns will be at the end or in mid.